# Delphi 2010 Search Wrap Around

Tags: delphi, search, delphi-2010

Is there any way to switch off the 'Wrapped around' functionality of Delphi 2010's search?

I understand lots of developers have issues with the new search function but it works well for me except when the search wraps around and goes to the first result again.

I also know that you can flag the Search selection box but this will not work for me. I miss the part of the search functionality that would let you search from cursor or scope and tell you when there are no more results.

An example of where this is messing me around. I have a tree view where lots of nodes are being accessed by level indexes (i.e. `Item.Level = 1`) and I need to add a new node at level 0 and thus all of the indexes needs to shift to Level + 1. I have wasted plenty of time now reassigning these indexes a second and even third time because the search function wraps (I cannot use the Replace for what I am doing).

It's a pain to watch the code scroll bar every time I change something and `.Level = 0` has become `.Level = 1`, `.Level = 2`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default behavior in `Delphi XE` is a dialog box that asks to *Restart search from the beginning of the file*, including an (unchecked) checkbox to *Wrap around without asking*.

This behavior is configurable in `Tools -> Options -> Editor Options -> Auto search wrap around`.

I don't have `Delphi 2010` running to verify but with any luck, this could be all it takes.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the same for Delphi 2010. Somehow I missed it when going through the options. Thank you again

Comment: XE3 is still the same too

Comment: I accidentally checked the option in the dialog and it has driven me to insanity. Thanks for saving my programming live ;) (working in Delphi 10.1 Berlin as well)